# get error instead of incompatible pointer type warning

Tags: c

In a C program I get "passing argument ... from incompatible pointer type" warnings, however I want to get error and terminate compilation instead of warning.

What flag shall I set in makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using gcc, I think the option combination you need is `-fstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-aliasing=3 -Werror=strict-aliasing`. See [this text](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wno_002dstrict_002daliasing-316) for documentation of the `strict-aliasing` option.

Comment: For gcc 4.6.3 still reports warning instead of error. BTW, in that documentation they say that `-Wstrict-aliasing=1` will trigger incompatible pointer type warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gcc, add the `-Werror` flag.

Comment: but I need only that type of warnings, not all

Comment: You can't select that only some warnings are treated as errors. It's all or nothing.

Comment: You can select specific warnings to become errors like `-Werror=format` (that id is from gcc output `warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat]`). But unfortunately for gcc 4.6.3 I get `incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]`. So it looks like `-Werror` the only way in this case. I used approach from @lee answer to turn some errors back to warning (like `-Wno-error=format`).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question.  The suggestions above didn't work something which comes closer is

gcc -Werror -Wno-error=all